# python - reading file, modifiing it and saving, but it is saved with no modifications. why?

Tags: python-2.7

I have files in this format: 01, 02, ... 10, 11, 12, ...
They are all html and i was trying to parse them a little.
But when i tried to do it, and save the files, it did happen, but with no changes.

```
from re import sub
for i in range (0,10):
    x = "0"
    if i<10:
        x="0"+str(i)
    if i>10:
        x=str(i)
    print x
    file = open(x+".html", "r") # opening file to read from
    r = file.read()
    file.close()
    filew = open(x+".parsed", "w") # opening file to write in
    r.replace('<br>', '/n')
    r.replace('"', '/"')
    sub('<[^<]*>', '', r) # delete all <tags>
    sub('<\/[^<]*>', '', r) # delete all </tags>
    filew.write(r)
    filew.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r.replace('<br>', '/n')
r.replace('"', '/"')
sub('<[^<]*>', '', r) # delete all <tags>
sub('<\/[^<]*>', '', r) # delete all </tags>
```

None of these lines do anything. Strings are immutable, so it's impossible for a function to modify the contents of an existing string. Instead, those functions will return a brand new string, which you must assign to something.

```
r = r.replace('<br>', '/n')
r = r.replace('"', '/"')
r = sub('<[^<]*>', '', r) # delete all <tags>
r = sub('<\/[^<]*>', '', r) # delete all </tags>
```